# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 sign in form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting into PHP/MySQL code and I've searched all over for a solution to this problem but no answers match my issue.

My code is very simple but I can't find whats causing this error

```
  <?php

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "langalungalangalunga";
  $password = "langalungalangalunga";
  $dbname = "user_main";

  $client_username = $client_password = $client_email = "";
  $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $emailErr = "";

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
      $client_username = test_input($_POST['username']);
    } else {
      $usernameErr = "No input on UserName";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $client_password = test_input($_POST['password']);
    } else {
      $passwordErr = "No input on Password";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
      $client_email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    } else {
      $emailErr = "No input on Email";
    }
  }

    function test_input($data) {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
   }

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO user_main (UserName, Password, Email)
      VALUES ($client_username, $client_password, $client_email)";
      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      echo "<script> alert('Success!');</script>";
      }
        catch(PDOException $e)
      {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }
        $conn = null;
     }
   ?>
```

The error points at line 2 of the email part

check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , email@email.com)' at line 2

```
<form class="" action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' method="post">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['username']) ?>">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" value="">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Register</button>
</form>
```

I am sorry if it's my mistake somewhere but I am new to PHP all together so I dont really have a feel for the syntax

Comment: string to be enclosed by single quotes in mysql and don't insert user data like this.it will lead to sql injection possibilities  use pdo bind parameter method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_main (`UserName`, `Password`, `Email`)
      VALUES ('$client_username', '$client_password', '$client_email')";

      $conn->query($sql);
```

The above code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements as

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_main (`UserName`, `Password`, `Email`)
VALUES (:UserName, :Password, :Email)");//placeholders
$stmt->bindParam(':UserName', $client_username);//you do not need to escape inputs
$stmt->bindParam(':Password', $client_password);
$stmt->bindParam(':Email', $client_email);

if($stmt->execute() == true){
//all good
echo'Data successfully saved Securely!';
} else {
 print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
 exit;
}
```

An extra tip. Do not store your passwords in plain text. Use `password_hash`

```
$hashedPassword = password_hash($client_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

On checking if the password matches the hash, use `password_verify`

```
 if(password_verify($client_password, $hashedPassword)){// do this when logging in or during some other authentication
    //all good
    echo 'Password is Correct';

    } else {
    echo 'Password is InCorrect.Sorry';
}
```

Comment: Got uncaught error 

That dont look too good , something wrong with my PDO Drivers?

Comment: Getting 

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: trying to execute an empty query

With final update of your answer... ?

Comment: just added the execute statement. I hope you aren't copying the whole code. Only copy the prepared statement section of my answer.

Comment: yea by bad , didnt close the TRY after implementing your solution. I dont really get how it works but it does and i guess i will understand it in time :D thanks alot brother, approved answer

About the password 

      $client_password = password_hash($_POST['password']);

that look ok ?

Answer (score 1):

change you insert sql code like below:

**Try this:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_main (UserName, Password, Email)
      VALUES ('".$client_username."', '".$client_password."', '".$client_email."')";
```

Comment: I be god-smacked that worked. Thank you Mahesh Singh Chouhan. What is the logic behind this? You are even using double quotes. How does that work and when should I use it ?